# Transpose in Pig

Tags: python, apache-pig

I have a dataset in Pig that goes like this:

```
Name Class Subject Marks  
Andy 1     Maths    10  
John 1     Maths    20  
Mark 2     Maths    20  
Tony 2     Geo      30
```

But I need to change it to:

```
Name Class Maths Geo  
Andy 1      10    0   
John 1      20    0   
Mark 2      20    0  
Tony 2      0    30
```

Can anyone suggest me on how to perform this within Pig?? Also, I am trying to write one Python script that will take the data and do a transpose on that.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are `Maths` and `Geo` the only subjects, or do you need to be able to handle more cases?

Answer (score 0):

grouping by (Name, Class) should give you a BAG which has all the marks of an student.  You can then write a simple UDF to take this BAG as input and generate the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Bharat for the answer...I will try on those lines and check whether its getting transposed in my way or not :)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to write the udf :(

Answer (score 0):

If your two subjects are already defined (I mean if your subjects are static), you can write this simple code to avoid writing an UDF :

```
A = LOAD .... AS Name, Class, Subject, Marks ...; 

B = FOREACH A GENERATE (Subject == 'Maths' ? Marks : 0) AS Maths, (Subject == 'Geo' ? Marks : 0) AS Geo, class, Name;
```

And if you want to aggregate your datas by Name and Class :

```
C = GROUP B BY (Name,class);

D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, sum(Maths) AS Maths, SUM(Geo) AS Geo;

E = FOREACH D GENERATE flatten(group), Maths, Geo;
```

Of course this snippet code works only if you have two defined subjects.. :)

Romain.